# Why is my object not changing when I reassign properties in a forEach loop?

Tags: arrays, typescript, foreach, rxjs

I am fetching an array of objects from an RX/JS call from an http backend. It returns an object which I am then trying to work with. I am making changes to this object using a for loop (in this example I am trying the `.forEach` because I have tried a number of different things and none of them seem to work.

When I run the code, I get a very weird problem. If I return the values of the properties, I get the new values (i.e. `correctionQueued` returns as true, etc.) but in the very next line, when I return the object, those same values are the same as the original (`correctionQueued` === false, etc.) HOWEVER, `correctionStatus` (which does not exist on the original object from http) sets just fine.

I don't understand how 
`array[index].correctionQueued` can return true, but
`array[index]` returns an object with `correctionQueued` as false.

After the loop, the original array (`checklistCopy`) is identical to the object before the `forEach` loop, except the new property (`correctionStatus`) is now set, but all properties that I changed that were part of the original object remain as they were.

I have tried using a for of, for in, and .forEach. I have used the index to alter the original array, always the same result. Preexisting properties do not change, new properties are added. I have even tried working on a copy of the object in case there is something special about the object returned from rxjs, but to no avail.

```
    checklistCopy.forEach((checklistItem, index, array) => {
      if (checklistItem.crCode.isirName === correctionSetItem) {
        array[index].correctionQueued = true;
        array[index].correctionValue = mostRecentCorrection.correctionValue;
        array[index].correctionStatus = mostRecentCorrection.status;
        console.log(array[index].correctionQueued, array[index].correctionValue, array[index].correctionStatus);
        console.log(array[index]);
      }
    }
    );
```

I don't get an error, but I get..

Original object is:

```
correctionQueued: false;
correctionValue: JAAMES;
```

--

```
console.log(array[index].correctionQueued, array[index].correctionValue, array[index].correctionStatus);
true JAMES            SENT
```

but when I print the whole object:

```
console.log(array[index]);

correctionQueued: false;
correctionValue: JAAMES;
correctionStatus: "SENT'; <-- This is set correctly but does not exist on original object.
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `array[index]` instead of just `checklistItem`?

Comment: No, I had tried it as checklistItem previously and the last thing I tried was array[index] just to see if it made a difference. I have now altered the code per Ryan's comment to use checklistItem but the output is the same.

Comment: If you could give us a [mre], with an example of the data that produces this result, we could likely help you. You could also use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make it runnable right here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log(array[index])` (at least in Chrome) just adds the object reference to the console.  The values do not resolve until you expand it, so your console log statement is not actually capturing the values at that moment in time.

Change your console statement to: `console.log(JSON.stringify(array[index]))` and you should discover that the values are correct at the time the log statement runs.

The behavior you are seeing suggests that something is coming along *later* and changing the object properties back to the original value.  Unless you show a more complete example, we can't help you find the culprit.  But hopefully this answers the question about why your logs show what they show.

Comment: This got me over the hump. I had always assumed that the object dumped to the console (I am using Firefox) was the object at the point at which it was output, not the object at the point at which I clicked to look at it. This got me looking elsewhere in the code and I found some old redundant code that was not commented out that was trying to do a simpler version of setting correction queued and value.

Answer (score 0):

Your output doesn't make sense to me either but cleaning up your code may help you. Try this:

```
checklistCopy.forEach(checklistItem => {
  checklistItem.correctionQueued = checklistItem.crCode.isirName === correctionSetItem;
  if (checklistItem.correctionQueued) {
      checklistItem.correctionValue = mostRecentCorrection.correctionValue;
      checklistItem.correctionStatus = mostRecentCorrection.status;
      console.log('checklistItem', checklistItem)
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: I altered the code to your suggestion but I got the identical output.